# Confused by the enumerate() function in tutorials

Tags: python, function

Actually I am learning python with some previously written scripts, I try to understand codes lines by line but in this code I don't know what exactly is going on (specially in  line 2):

```
def convertSeq(s, index):
    result = [i + 1 for i, ch in enumerate(s) if ch == '1']
    result = ' '.join([str(index) + ':' + str(i) for i in result])
    result = str(index) + ' ' + result
    return result
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate` returns an iterator(`enumerate object`), which yields `tuples` containing index and item from the iterable/itertator passed to it.

```
>>> text = 'qwerty'
>>> it = enumerate(text)
>>> next(it)
(0, 'q')
>>> next(it)
(1, 'w')
>>> next(it)
(2, 'e')
>>> list(enumerate(text))
[(0, 'q'), (1, 'w'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'r'), (4, 't'), (5, 'y')]
```

So, the list comprehension in your code is actually equivalent to:

```
>>> text = '12121'
>>> result = []
for item in enumerate(text):
    i, ch = item              #sequence unpacking
    if ch == '1':
        result.append(i+1)
...         
>>> result
[1, 3, 5]
```

In fact you can also pass the starting point of the index to the enumerate, so your list comprehesion can be changed to:

```
result = [i for i, ch in enumerate(s, start=1) if ch == '1']
```

---

`enumerate` is usually preferred over something like this:

```
>>> lis = [4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in xrange(len(lis)):
    print i,'-->',lis[i]
...     
0 --> 4
1 --> 5
2 --> 6
3 --> 7
```

Better:

```
>>> for ind, item in enumerate(lis):
    print ind,'-->', item
...     
0 --> 4
1 --> 5
2 --> 6
3 --> 7
```

`enumerate` will work on iterators as well:

```
>>> it = iter(range(5, 9))      #Indexing not possible here
for ind, item in enumerate(it):
    print ind,'-->', item
...     
0 --> 5
1 --> 6
2 --> 7
3 --> 8
```

Help on `enumerate`:

```
class enumerate(object)
 |  enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
 |  
 |  Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
 |  iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
 |  start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
 |  enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
 |      (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

enumerate iterates over an iterator, and returns a tuple with current index and the current item.

```
>>> for i in range(100,105):
...     print(i)
... 
100
101
102
103
104
>>> for info in enumerate(range(100,105)):
...     print(info)
... 
(0, 100)
(1, 101)
(2, 102)
(3, 103)
(4, 104)
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruv nicely explained

Comment: `enumerate` can iterate over both iterable and iterator.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new iterator from any iterable object, which returns the values in the original object, together with an index starting from `0`. For example

```
lst = ["spam", "eggs", "tomatoes"]

for item in lst:
  print item

# spam
# eggs
# tomatoes

for i, item in enumerate(lst):
   print i, item

# 0 spam
# 1 eggs
# 2 tomatoes
```

Answer (score 0):

[enumarate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a python built-in function to help you to keep track of the indexes of the sequence.

See the following code:

```
    >>>sequence = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    >>>
    >>>list(enumerate(sequence)) # prints [(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, 'baz')]
    >>>
    >>>zip(range(len(sequence)), sequence) # prints [(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, 'baz')]
    >>>for item in sequence:
    ......print (item, sequence.index(item))
    ('foo', 0)
    ('bar', 1)
    ('baz', 2)
```

As you can see, the results are the same, but with enumerate it is easier to write, read and it is more efficient in some cases.